# Algorithm to find clusters (min x pts. within y distance of cluster center) of geographical points

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, latitude-longitude, geo

Given a database of geographical locations (long/lat), what would be the best approach to determining/detecting clusters of locations that are within x miles of the cluster center AND total at least y locations?

e.g. out of 1000 McWidgets in NC, there are 30 clusters each containing 20 or more stores within 7 miles of their respective cluster center.

It's been a long time since my applied math course in college... any help for an old mushy brain would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

A common method for this kind of problem is [Density-based Spatial Clustering of Applications with Noise (DBSCAN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).  A variation which may be a better choice, if you can't determine a good density parameter, is the [Ordering Points To Identify the Clustering Structure (OPTICS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) algorithm, which uses a distance parameter, rather than a density parameter.

Comment: The OPTICS algorithm seems like a possible solution... thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need one of the [Clustering algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Clustering_Algorithms).